# Adding PIP to Existing VirtualEnv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have created a virtualenv using the following command:

`python3 -m venv --without-pip ./env_name`

I am now wondering if it is possible to add PIP to it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will find this useful. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/581648/install-package-into-virtualenv-using-apt-get

You can download the pip module and copy it to your env.

Answer (score 0):

download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

then run this command

```
python get-pip.py
```

and [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: Would this install it globally or into environment? I already have pip globally. I only need to add it to the environment.

Comment: installs in active environment

Comment: I asked another question related to this. Do you think it would help if i did what you are suggesting?

Comment: This does not work. I get the following: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 2.5MB/s 
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0
`

Comment: As you can see it tries to install the pip into the system directory, even though I have activated the env.

Comment: do you call active script for new virtual env? `source env_name/bin/activate` (each time you want to work with this env you should run this command to change python path from default to your env)

Comment: I tried it and it worked, what does comannd `which python` prints?

Comment: To make the long story short, there was something wrong with the `virtualenv`. I had to run an update and only then it started behaving as one would expect.